# How do you require('backbone') properly?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, webpack, laravel-elixir

I'm trying to include Backbone into my existing Laravel Spark/Vuejs application which is becoming an SPA very quickly. Spark includes multiple libraries from NPM using code like:

```
window._ = require('underscore'); 
if (window.$ === undefined || window.jQuery === undefined) {
    window.$ = window.jQuery = require('jquery');
}
```

When I try to require Backbone like this:

```
window.Backbone = require('backbone');
```

or simply:

```
require('backbone');
```

It doesn't work. Backbone is undefined.

NB: Underscore and jQuery are both required previous to my attempting to require Backbone, as shown above.

Here's the question:

Why can Spark seemingly "register" multiple libraries with the window (as I showed above), but when I attempt to do this with Backbone, it does not seem to take?

EDIT:

Importing Backbone and using it in the same module **does work**, but my goal is to allow global usage of Backbone, similar to globally using _ and $. I realize this is frowned upon, but I honestly cannot determine for myself why placing Backbone into global scope at this point would be a negative.

Laravel Elixir config (which employs webpack):

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.less('app.less')
        .webpack('app.js', null, null, {
            resolve: {
                modules: [
                    path.resolve(__dirname, 'vendor/laravel/spark/resources/assets/js'),
                    'node_modules'
                ]
            }
        })
        .copy('node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js', 'public/js/sweetalert.min.js')
        .copy('node_modules/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.css', 'public/css/sweetalert.css')
        .version(['css/app.css', 'js/app.js']);
});
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] of the configuration you're using.

Comment: Could you please be more specific on what you need to know? My question is fairly general. I have edited it to make it more clear what I am looking to do.

Comment: In fact, the subject of this question is the real question: How do you require('backbone') properly? I do not see one example in the Backbonejs docs, or anywhere else for that matter.

Comment: It really depends on your webpack config, because just _requiring_ backbone is trivial.

Comment: Well, I guess that's part of the issue. Laravel Elixir (now Mix) abstracts a lot of the Webpack config, so I am not extremely familiar with it. Are you saying there is Webpack configuration that allows certain required libraries to be attached to the window, while others would not be allowed? Using `window.whatever = require('whatever')` would not result in the same outcome in all cases, depending on the Webpack config? If so, what configuration options would modify this behavior?

Comment: I'm personally not that familiar with webpack configurations, but without it, it's unlikely you'll get good answers. I was just asking you to provide the  config so you'll get better help, not necessarily from me.

Comment: Understood. I've edited the post to include more details. Thank you.